# How would I autofill a value based on the date in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two tables in excel, and I need to autofill in the selected values (hours lights were on) for each of those days. What would I put in the cell to automate that?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1StJdK80iS2RuAfFHoUrCVK60wxq8ZzLWTORo5FHqM8M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the VLOOKUP function...
The syntax of [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is: `VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

- **lookup_value**: Is the value you want to look up
- **table_array**: This is the table of data that you want to find the `lookup_value` in
- **col_index_num**: This is the column number of the data you want it to return
- **[range_lookup]**: *(optional)* This is whether or not to find an exact match (which most often you want an exact match, so you would put FALSE)

In your case you would put VLOOKUP in J5 to J34:

- Your `lookup_value` would be the date one cell to the left of your lookup cells. (In column I)
- Your `table_array` would be A2:D371 (or if you add more data this value would change)
- The `column_index` would be 3 because you want the data from the 3rd column
- And just put `FALSE` in for `[range_lookup]`, because you want an exact match

So you could put `VLOOKUP(I5, $A$2:$D$371, 3, FALSE)` in cell J5 and then drag it down all the rows you want it in.

If you want to see this in action, here is a copy of your sheet with the VLOOKUP function added in: [Copy of LIGHTSON](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mj6ny2g39u73xEwFSTbiuBGytUNydmIPtuvGLZvaT4M/edit?usp=sharing)

Hope this helps!